# Question about contractible set .

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Please if i have a contractible and closed set $A$ in $X$

thene $A$ is closed and there existe a continuous function $H:[0,1]\times A\rightarrow X$ such that $H(0,u)=u, H(1,u)=p\in X.$

If i consider $h$ and $\beta$ two continuous functions

Is $h\circ\beta\circ H(1,A)$ contractible ? and what about $\overline{h\circ\beta \circ H(1,A)}$ is it contractible ?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't $H(1,A) = \{p\}$ or what else do you mean by $H(1,A)$? I assume it means $\{H(1,u) : u \in A \} = H[\{1\} \times A]$. And how do you compose a singleton with a function ?

Comment: yes it is, the composition is well defined, in auther word i want to see if the image by continuous map of a contractible set stay contractible

Comment: The continuous image of a contractible set like $[0,1]$ can be any Peano continuum, so e.g. $S^1$ which is not contractible.